# Fetch Request not getting one object property

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, file, fetch-api

I pass on a fetch post an object which includes a file parsed as a binary string, but on the request I'm getting everything except the file property. I understand not receiving it as a file object but its already a string so not sure what's happening or what am I missing.

Client:

```
 var fileReader = new FileReader();

$('#form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var data = {}
    data.materiales = []
    data.fecha = new Date().toISOString().split('.')[0]
    var file = {}
    $("#formHeader :input,select").each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != ''){
            data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
        }
    });

    $("[name = materiales]").each(function(){
        var obj = {}
        $(this).find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != ''){
            if ($(this).attr('name') == "pdf"){
                fileReader.onload = function(){ obj.file = fileReader.result.toString()}
                fileReader.readAsBinaryString( $(this).prop('files')[0])
            }
                else
                obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
        }
        })
        data.materiales.push(obj)        
    });
    console.log(data)

    fetch("/vale", {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {

                    return response.json();
                }
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            })
            .then(responseJSON => {

                window.location.href = "/ordenes-compra/"
            })
            .catch(err => {

                alert(err.message)
            })

})
```

As you can see I have a console.log which displays:

```
{
"materiales": [
    {
        "codigo": "423423",
        "descripcion": "Prueba",
        "cantidad": "55",
        "file": "%PDF-1.4\n%âãÏÓ\n1 0 obj\n<</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 1824/Length 161263/Height 695/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream\nÿØÿà\u0000\"
    }
],
"fecha": "2022-08-25T15:20:00",
"pedidoPara": "Almacen",
"proyecto": "ABS",
"departamento": "Armado"
}
```

The file string is too long so I cut it, (365kb)
Server:

```
router.post('/vale/', async(req, res) => {;

console.log(req.body.materiales)

});
```

This only displays:

```
[ { codigo: '423423', descripcion: 'Prueba', cantidad: '55' } ]
```

I also tried console.log(req.body.materiales.file)
but gives me undefined

Comment: return `file` value as string type, you might be a passing an object or something else.

Comment: You can see on the console log that file its a string

Comment: I see the issue with ending `\` you should escape properly the response before returning it.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Google search how to escape string & slash in your working language. I don't know what language you're using on the server side.